# How does the browser plugin Disconnect work?

Tags: plugins, browser, privacy

I've recently installed the browser plugin [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/) to keep Facebook, Twitter and Google from recording my browser history as I use the regular web while still letting me use those services when I choose to.

Can anyone explain how Disconnect works?

I'm interested in how it works to understand where my web experience might be changed or compromised and as an intellectual curiosity about what these sites are doing and how it can be blocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are detailed descriptions of what our extensions do in the extension galleries (and someday soon, our site), e.g.:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jeoacafpbcihiomhlakheieifhpjdfeo

More technically, all our extension code is open source (and well commented and otherwise readable, if I do say so myself):

https://github.com/disconnectme

Comment: What will no longer work when I am browsing the web now that Disconnect is running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing, but to track you, google, facebook and twitter send you a cookie to identify you. Then if you browse the web a display page that contain an adsense banner, a g+1 button an analytic script, a facebook/twitter widget, google , facebook and tweeter access this cookie.

So to prevent them to record your browsing, maybe the addon filter the cookie sent in http request or filter google/fb/twitter script/iframe/url from the viewed page.

Hope this could give you a hint.

Regards

Comment: I think you've got this backwards.  A g+1 button doesn't send you a cookie to identify you - your browser sends the g+1 server a cookie that identifies you when the browser makes it's web request associated with the g+1 button.  Perhaps cookie blocking is part of the process, but I'd like to know how it actually works rather than guesses.

Comment: Sorry it may have sound backwards, but i meant what you explained. Anyway, this is a browser addon so i think you can easily get the sources and it should be in javascript. Hope you won't be afraid.

Comment: I can tell you from my test, that for the facebook block, It does not allow any facebook widget to load (iframes)